# Customized first post techniques

Tags: custom-post-types, paged

There doesn't seem to be a standard technique for differentiating first/top posts. After looking around, I found this method:

```
$current_query = new WP_Query('post_type=current&post_status=publish'); 

// Pull out top/first post
$first_post = ( $paged == 0 ) ? $posts[0]->ID : '';

while ($current_query->have_posts()) : $current_query->the_post();

if ($first_post == $post->ID) {
    echo '<div class="post top-post-special" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
} else {
    echo '<div class="post" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
}
```

This relies on $paged (which seems to be a Wordpress built-in) to add the "top-post-special" class in first post as expected. However, when using the following query_post instead of a new WP_Query instance, it no longer works:

```
$args=array(
          'taxonomy' => 'highlights',
            'term' => 'Featured',
          'post_type' => 'highlights',
        );

query_posts($args); 

$first_post = ( $paged == 0 ) ? $posts[0]->ID : '';         

if ( have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();                 

if ($first_post == $post->ID) {
    echo '<div class="post top-post-special" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
} else {
    echo '<div class="post" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
}
```

I thought the second would be analogous to the first, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is there a better or standardized way to target the first post? Seems like this would come up a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do any special queries for this. Here is one way to accomplish it

```
/**
 * conditional check ensures special class only shows on top post on first page.
 * if you want top post on page 2, etc. to have special class, just set $first_post to true
 */
if( (int) get_query_var( 'paged' ) > 1 ){
    $first_post = false;
} else {
    $first_post = true;
}

if ( have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();                 

if ( $first_post ) {
    echo '<div class="post top-post-special" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
    $first_post = false;
} else {
    echo '<div class="post" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could change the one line to:

```
$first_post = ( !is_paged() ) ? $posts[0]->ID : '';
```

or use a different approach:

```
if ($wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) {
       echo '<div class="post top-post-special" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">'; 
} else {
       echo '<div class="post" id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">'; 
}
```

Comment: First one didn't work, but the different approach did. I've given the nod to previous poster, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        // set class for first post on first page
        $class = (!is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post === 0) ? 'top-post-special' : '';
?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $class ); ?>>

</div>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried testing this but couldn't get post_class to behave.  It passed the parameter fine, but for some reason wouldn't output the post class itself. Thank you for the response.